# How to turn on Autosave in Fifa 12

Tags: fifa-12

Can someone tell me that How to turn on Autosave in FIFA 12 (Career Mode)

Details :-

- Fifa 12 (2011)
- Platform : PC
- Mode : Career
- Windows 8 / 10

Comment: Ask this in the EA forums: http://forum.ea.com/uk/categories/show/16.page

Answer (score 1):

Autosave should be enabled by default for this game and it's not possible to turn this off. After each game you play autosave replace a secondary save and call it "Career Mode Autosave" + #. But you still can manually save your game under your main save so you can reload it at any time you wish. Please check all of your saves to ensure you have your game autosaved.